# MVC 4 Asp.net ,using File Upload code How to save images in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**here is my view**

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table> 
    <tr>

<td>File :</td>    
    <td><input type="file" name="File" id="file" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" /></td>
  </tr>
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Picture picture)
        {
            if (picture.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(picture.File.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), fileName);
                picture.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


and Model:

namespace FileUpload.Models
{
    public class Picture
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }



    }
```

This code helps me to save image in my MVC project root Image folder , but I want to save it to my database . I have tried many tutorial but could not succeed yet ... '
I am Actually making the student form every student will register his picture.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image into bytes and then store it in your database

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Picture picture)
        {
            byte[] Image;
            if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
            {
               using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["file"].InputStream))
                {
                   Image = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);
                }
               Picture.File =Image;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Model

```
public class Picture
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
    }
```

View For Displaying Image

```
if (Model.File != null)
  {
     string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.File );
     string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
     <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
  }
```

Comment: Could you please give me a solution that how can I retrieve those Image from database and show in 'Index' view..

Comment: Is not those code I should be write in 'View' model ?? In my View model compiler does not resolve '@imageSrc' word and another query, when I write your upload method that time compiler automatic convert 'Picture Model' byte[] as static....why this happens ??

Comment: @mgsdew actually i am not getting it...can you post your code

Comment: My partner already post this problem in Stack Overflow..kindly check the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590604/how-to-retrieve-image-from-database/23590699?noredirect=1#comment36229105_23590699

Comment: @mgsdew show me the code for retrieving image from db which you have done and remove static keyword from model `static byte[] Image`

Comment: I don't write any code for retrieve image from database. Because I don't know how to retrieve. I only cope/paste your given code what my partner share the given link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52496/discussion-between-mgsdew-and-nilesh)