# How to Retrieve Image from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to retrieve Image from database and display it same controller 'Index' view or other controller 'Index' view. I think already I successfully insert Image data in database. Here is my code..Can anybody help me that what action/method and 'Html' form now I should write in my code..

Model class `Picture`:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

`PictureController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Picture picture)
{
        byte[] Image;
        if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
        {
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["file"].InputStream))
            {
                Image = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);
            }
            Picture.Image = Image;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pictures.Add(picture);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(picture);
    }
```

`Create` view of `PictureController`

```
 @model PartialView.Models.Picture

 @{ ViewBag.Title = "Create";   }

   <h2>Create</h2>

   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, 
     new { enctype = "multipart/form- data" }))
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Picture</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <td>File :</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" /> </td>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>  }
<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

Database table after insert of two data rows:

```
PictureId    Name
-------------------------
    1        Song
    2        Clothes
```

Comment: I would recommend that you store the content type that you get during the upload in your database as well. Then you can set the same content type when the image is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display image in the UI you need to define a controller action which has a return type of filecontentresult. following is an example :

```
public FileContentResult getImg(int id)
{
    byte[] byteArray = DbContext.Persons.Find(id).Image;
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Once you have defined the controller action then you can use following line of code to show the byte[] as an image in the view.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "Person", new { id = item.Id })" alt="Person Image" />
```

Comment: please mark as answer if you think this helped your to solve your problem.

Comment: When I write Upload method in my first controller it automatic convert 'Image'declaration as 'Static'. So, when I write your given method in my controller it does not get 'Image' as it declare as 'Static'. So how can I solve this problem now ??

Comment: Static? What do you mean convert it to static method? Could you be more specific? Show me upload code?

Comment: I already post my upload code in 'Picture Controller' 'HttpPost' method

Comment: what's the issue with uploading? What you mean by become static?

Comment: Please check my full code.. I post here all of my code..When I write 'Upload' method in 'Index' view that time it automatic convert my 'Model' declaration as 'Static'. I don't want to convert it 'Static'. I simply want upload image in database and retrieve them for show in 'Index' view.